# Exibir mapa estático Google com Picasso no Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-maps, picasso

Estou desenvolvendo um app pelo Android Studio, eu gostaria de criar uma RecyclerView onde tivesse uma ImageView e nela carregasse uma imagem estática de um determinando ponto no mapa.

Como aqui: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/intro

Tentei utilizar esse método com o Picasso (Biblioteca que pega imagem de uma url e carrega num ImageView) mas nada acontece, com outras urls de imagens na internet que eu usei pra testar ele funcionou e carregou no ImageView mas com essa não aparece nada:

```
imageMap = findViewById(R.id.imageMap);

        String lat = "-12.958811";
        String lon = "-38.401606";

        String url ="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?";
        url+="&zoom=14";
        url+="&size=330x130";
        url+="&maptype=roadmap";
        url+="&markers=color:green%7Clabel:G%7C"+lat+", "+lon;
        url+="&key=AQUI_VEM_A_MINHA_KEY";

        Picasso.get().load(url).into(imageMap);
```

Alguém sabe como fazer isso, com esse ou outro método?

Comment: A sua ideia é boa! Não entendo porque não funciona... Os parâmentros da URL estão corretos?

Comment: @AndreiCoelho SIm, mas se vc coloca o link no navegador pode ver que ele não carrega a imagem da mesma forma

Comment: Aqui a imagem carregou normalmente. Sua chave está valida?

Comment: Lembre-se, você precisa ativar a api `Maps Static API`

Comment: @LMaker Eu ativei Maps Static API sim, a chave está válida para dispositivo Android, eu utilizo ela para exibir o mapa completo no meu app e funciona normalmente

Comment: @LMaker Ok, eu consegui finalmente carregar o mapa no navegador, realmente a API estava ativada mas n estava associada a aquela chave. Mas ele não carrega no App pelo Picasso, testei com a url de outras imagens comuns e carregou de boa :(